# How to synchronize 2+ workers that listen on a message queue and share a database

Tags: c#, sql-server, concurrency, synchronization, message-queue

So I have the following setup:

- Web API (entry point)
- MSSQL DB (single)
- Worker service (listens on RabbitMQ)

The general idea is to send a POST to the Web API, which would put a message on a single queue (always the same). The listening worker service would then pick it up and process it.

The problem arises when I need to make sure that 2+ worker services are able to be deployed, listening on the same queue. This is because the work of the service is to process multiple `Document` entities. These are stored in a shared MSSQL Database where the schema for `Document` looks something like this:

```
+------------+---------+------------+-----+
| ID         | DocName | DocVersion | ... |
+------------+---------+------------+-----+
|          1 | Doc_ABC |          1 | ... |
|          2 | Doc_DEF |          3 | ... |
|          3 | Doc_GHI |          1 | ... |
|          4 | Doc_ABC |          2 | ... |
|          5 | Doc_DEF |          4 | ... |
|          6 | Doc_GHI |          2 | ... |
+------------+---------+------------+-----+
```

Assuming the above schema, this is the run-down of what the worker is supposed to do after receiving a message:

1. Fetch the "latest"(version-wise) document entries. This basically means it group on the `DocName` then filters on `DocVersion` MAX and returns the whole entry. So in other words it returns a row with the MAX version for each distinct `DocName` (they are more or less fixed)
2. Then, for each `Document` fetched, build a new document (business-logic stuff..) **with incremented version**
3. Send the document to an external API (**this will be rejected if the document version isn't higher than the previously sent document**)
4. Save the document to DB

This obviously introduces a race condition which is what this question is about. If a request is sent to the API (hence a worker is triggered) multiple times in succession, 2 messages will be published and both workers will get the same "latest" documents and therefore will eventually try to upload same versions.

In the example table above, both workers would get `Doc_ABC v2`, `Doc_DEF v4` and `Doc_GHI v2`. This will then result in 6 attempts to send a document and 3 of those documents will be rejected due to the version having been sent already.

I've tried to wrap this whole process (Steps 1-4) inside an isolated transaction scope, but I could still see the race condition. I've tried other approaches, changing the order of some of the calls etc without any success but I still believe there might be a logical solution to this.

Does anyone have an idea for solving this race condition?

**EDIT:** One thing I should have mentioned is that I do not need the parallelism, I just need it to be deterministic with 2+ queue consumers for fail-over purposes.

Comment: What if add another column to your table indicating which worker currently works with given item? Then after first worker grabs some item - second worker cannot grab the same one.

Comment: Doing what Evk suggests is also tricky, you might move the race condition to determining which worker works on the next item instead. If you go this route queries must be done with isolation level serializable which may seriously hurt performance since only one worker may access the docment table at once.

Comment: I added an important note at the end of the question regarding the performance.

Comment: For now I'll try Evk's suggestion and see if I can get it working. I'll report back when I've done that.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make sure that RabitMQ is setup correctly so that the same message is not delivered to multiple workers at the same time. See https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-python.html for more information on how this can be done. It seems to handle the scenario when one of the worker dies.

Also you will also need to be able to detect whenever a incoming request is duplicated, preferably before the message is put in the queue, but how to solve this in your situation is difficult without a full understanding of the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have two spots to check.

1) prevent it up front by having the API not allow multiple updates with the same data. Maybe track the last X requests in memory and ignore duplicates?

2) On your worker process, make sure to not ack the message until the work is complete, but maybe have it check the current item details if it fails to update. Then say if they match then still call it a success?

It depends on your business rules. Should the API send a fail response is multiple request already sent? Does it always just return a success?

Does the worker response matter?

How do you want to handle multiple *different* updates? Append changes? Overwrite?

Have a request sent timestamp along with the version to compare against updated time?